# Converting array into polynomial

Tags: matlab, polynomials

In MATLAB, there exists a function `ppval` for evaluation of polynomials in points, which given the polynomial in opportune format and the points where to evaluate it as input, returns the vector of the evaluations. Now I have built a function that finds the coefficients of a certain polynomial. Is there a function that, given an array of coefficients, converts it to the polynomial format `ppval` works with? Or do I have to build a function that evaluates the polynomial myself?

Comment: The function that evaluates the polynomial is `polyval`. So the question becomes theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html):

> Y = POLYVAL(P,X) returns the value of a polynomial P evaluated at X. P
>       is a vector of length N+1 whose elements are the coefficients of the
>       polynomial in descending powers.
>
> ```
>     Y = P(1)*X^N + P(2)*X^(N-1) + ... + P(N)*X + P(N+1)
> ```

Note `ppval` is for evaluation piecewise-polynomial functions, rather than polynomials.